# File Uploading Class in codeigniter using Url

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, upload

There is a way that i can use the to upload a image usen the File Uploading Class in codeigniter ???

im using the this example and works https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

but a want to use a url in a Text field  insted a `<input type="file" name="userfile"/>`

Sorry, English is not my native language
use a url to upload an image, like using a curl but with the File Uploading Class

Comment: Please rephrase your question. What exactly are you trying to do and what is the problem that you are facing? As I understand the question, you want to use a normal `<input type="text">` field to upload an image, but it is not very clear if that is your question.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language
what you say is what I want to do, use a url to upload an image, like using a curl

Answer (score 0):

No, the File Uploading Class if for users uploading a file through a form.

You'll want to get the URL from your text field, and then use something like [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the contents and write them to a file on your server.